# Caption Formation for Figure

Tags: floats, captions, formatting

I use the `caption` package.
Somehow I got a period between the type (Figure) and the separator (:)
When I wrote

```
listformat=empty,
```

for the Table of Figures, I just got the period and then the caption text.

I have no idea, but the period just appeared when I tried to skip the chapter numbering

```
(\counterwithout{figure}{chapter})
```

One way or the other, I always have the period which looks like:

```
Figure 1.: Description
```

EDIT:
I tried it, but I couldn't get it to run. That's everything I have regarding the captions. But somehow I think somewhere is some more. I just can't remember.

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % Schriftgröße
%DIV10,  % Teilung der Seite in 10 Teile (Layout bessere Lesbarkeit)
ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
a4paper, % Papierformat
oneside, % einseitiges Dokument (Standard)
titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
%index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
listof=flat,
captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben
final % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[
labelfont=bf,
%   labelsep=none,
listformat=simple,  % simple ist defaultwert.
]{caption}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}




\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{foo.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption{Beispiel einer Matrixkombination}
\label{fig:Matrixknoten}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: A full but [minimal example](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl) would be very helpful.

Comment: I am aware of that, but since I cant reproduce the mistake, I cannot upload anything. I cannot strip my document far enough to load it up. :-(

Comment: But with the information you gave it is nearly impossible to give specific help. There is something in your code that seems cause this misbehaviour. But without seeing that code the problem is incomprehensible (at least for me).

Comment: does this help?

Comment: @MiKa I fixed your code so that it compiles, but your example doesn't actually show the problem you're having.  Have you redefined `\thefigure` anywhere in your actual document?

Comment: I just had a look, I didn't redefine \thefigure. thx by the way @Alan

Comment: @MiKa what about `\captionformat` or `\figureformat`?

Comment: @Alan, not those neither. But I tried \thefigure again, then I had two numbers, and also the point.

Comment: @MiKa I'm not sure what you mean by your last comment.

Comment: @Alan I tried to use \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\textbf{\arabic{figure}}: }, but then I got 2 numbers and also the point: Figure 1 2.:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In document class 
    `scrreprt`
if you use the Appendix, you automatically get a period after the number.
To solve the problem you need to load the class with the option:

```
numbers=noendperiod
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: since you have found the solution to your own problem, you should accept your own answer. (You may have to wait a day to do this, but please come back and accept it when you can.)

Comment: @Alan: I know I have to, but I can't, I have to wait 2 days. :-S That should be changed...

Comment: It is sometimes annoying, but I don't think it's going to change.  I was just reminding you in case you weren't aware that you can actually accept your own answer (which you are.)

Comment: @Alan, that's very thoughtful of you, thank's.